# Spring Hibernate mapping based on composite primary key and interface

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I've searched on Stackoverflow but did not really find the answer to my question. Anyways, here is a rough schema of what I'm trying to build with spring:

```
ConcreteToolA
-------------
id(pk)
....

ConcreteToolB
-------------
id(pk)
....

Resource
--------
id(pk)
name
...

UsedResource
------------------
resource_id(pk)
tool_id(pk)
tool_type(pk)
quantity
....
```

And in Java I have something like this:

```
public interface Tool {

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ConcreteToolA")
public class ConcreteToolA implements Tool {

    @OneToMany
    private List<UsedResource> resources;
    private int toolType = Const.A;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ConcreteToolB")
public class ConcreteToolB implements Tool {

    @OneToMany
    private List<UsedResource> resources;
    private int toolType = Const.B;

}

@Enity
@Table(name = "Resource")
public class Resource {

    private String name;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "UsedResource")
public class UsedResource{

    //one-to-many reference to tool
    private Tool usedBy;
    private int quantity;

}
```

To sum up, I want a generic way to link resources with different (abstract) entities like tools in my case. But in the future there might come up further tools or other more abstract entities that can consume resources (people etc.). Therefore I want to link the relation (UsedResource) with an interface and need probably some kind of custom setter?

Maybe I only used the wording search terms and it was already explain multiple times... If someone could help me here I'd be happy.

Comment: Your question is not focused strictly on how this could be handled across the `Java` domain `@Entity` objects, you would also like some help with the `Hibernate` mapping as well, correct?

Comment: Well, the thing is I'm not sure how to implement such a pattern with Spring and Hibernate as I'm new to Hibernate. I've done some Google research and probably I might get some kind of patchwork solution but then I still don't know what's best way for something like this.

Comment: Okay, just wanted to understand the scope of your question. Taking a second look, based on your response, and I have a question: the `ConcreteToolA` and `ConcreteToolB` entities include a `@Table` annotation; however, `UsedResource` does not. Is there a reason for that omission?

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I adjusted the things. In the meantime I also checked out the CompositeUserType of hibernate to handle the usedBy reference to a tool. And I that type I probably need to create the concrete tool based on the tool_type